# creating class as Iterable in angular/typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, iterable

I have created a class in angular, now when I fetch an object via store subscription, although it returns an array of object, but I cannot use forEach loop on the returned object.

Yes, I have used **Object.keys(user).forEach(){..}** It is working, but I want to do the same thing by making class Iterable. How To this.

Sample code:-

```
class user {
    ...
}
ngOnInit(){
    storeSubsc = this.store.select('users').subscribe(user => {
        this.user = user;
    });
}

login(){
    Object.keys(this.user).forEach()... --> working fine
    I want it like
    this.user.forEach() {... }
}
```

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, what you wish to achieve is an iterable of `this.user`'s keys instead of using `Object.keys()`?

Comment: yes.., something like 
this.user.forEach(ele => {
console.log(ele):
}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order for your class to be iterable, your class needs to have a method of `Symbol.iterator`:

```
class User implements Iterable<string> {
    // ...
    constructor(private username: string, private password: string) { }

    *[Symbol.iterator](): Iterator<string> {
        for (let key of Object.keys(this)) {
            yield key;
        }
    }
}

const u = new User('blabla', '1234');
for (let k of u) {
    console.log(k);
}
```

In this case I used a generator function.

Comment: *(Just be careful of browser support, IE doesn't know about that)*

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for in` operator:

```
class User {
  // 
}

const user = new User(/*args*/); 
for (let prop in user) {
  console.log(prop, user[prop]);
}
```

Additionally, you can check if the class instance has the `prop` as its own property `user.hasOwnProperty(prop)` inside the `for in` loop. For example, if your `User` class extends another base class and without checking `hasOwnProperty` you will see the `constructor` as well:

```
class BaseUser {
  constructor(public x, public y) { }
}

class User extends BaseUser {
  constructor(public a, public b, public x, public y) {
    super(x, y);
  }
}

const user = new User('12', 2, 111, 222); 
for (let prop in user) {
  alert(prop);
}
```

You will see five alerts: `x, y, a, b, constructor`.